# Changing the default numbering scheme in enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

Together with a colleague I'm writing a book (with the Springer template), and I am currently homogenizing the layout. I'd like to change the default numbering scheme in the enumerate environment **globally** in the beginning of the document so that I don't have to tack on the modifier at the end of every “\begin{enumerate}**[(1)]**” — and change it once my co-author decides he prefers (i), (ii), etc. or some other way to number lists. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `enumitem` package and `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\alpha*)}}` in the preamble. You can change later on to `label=(\roman*)`. This will set the first level only

Answer (score 8):

Use `enumitem` for example and set the list parameters.

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\arabic*)}}
```

will  use `(1)` for the first level, `\roman*` will change to `(i)` etc.

If you need the `enumerate` package style, then use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` however.

The settings are persistent after a `\setlist` has been used.

Please note, that the `2nd` and deeper levels are not changed automatically!.

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{font={\bfseries}}% global settings, for all lists
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\arabic*)}}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item Is
\item Absolutely necessary
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item And
\item Now
\item For
\item Something
\item Completely
\item Different
\end{enumerate}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\roman*)}}



\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item Is
\item Absolutely necessary
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item And
\item Now
\item For
\item Something
\item Completely
\item Different
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked … although I will need to change the code when I override the enumeration scheme (which is not a problem).

Comment: @MaxLein: well, you can define your own lists with `\newlist`, that can have their specific scheme.